# Increase the font size of a TextView in gtkmm-4.0

Tags: c++, user-interface, gtkmm4

Assume that We have this simple application, a `Gtk::TextView` inside a window. I use gtkmm-4.0

*mainwindow.h*

```cpp
#pragma once
#include <gtkmm.h>
class mainwindow : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
    mainwindow();

protected:
    Gtk::TextView myTextEntry;
};
```

*mainwindow.cpp*

```cpp
#include "mainwindow.h"

mainwindow::mainwindow()
{
    this->set_default_size(300,300);
    this->set_child(myTextEntry);
}
```

*main.cpp*

```cpp
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create();

    return app->make_window_and_run<mainwindow>(argc,argv);
}
```

here is the output:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ewJuR.png)

I wanna make the font size of the `myTextEntry` a bit larger how can i do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

OK.This is how I did it. I had to style my app using the `Gtk::CssProvider` class. basically you define a class with a name in css language. you name your widget using `name()` method it (both with same name) then give that css class to your wigdet using `get_style_context()->add_provider()`:

In My `mainwindow.h` to the `protected:` section add `Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::CssProvider> provider;`

then i went to the body the constructor in `mainwindow.cpp` and added this:

```cpp
provider=Gtk::CssProvider::create();
provider->load_from_data("#MainCodeText{"
        "font-size:22px;"
    "}");
myTextEntry.set_name("MainCodeText");
myTextEntry.get_style_context()->add_provider(TextViewStyle,1);
```

note that you can use another methods of `CssProvider` to import your css style you can add it from file (`load_from_file`) or a path (`load_from_path`) or a simple string like I did. so for my example that code i mentioned in the above is something like this.

*mainwindow.h*

```
#pragma once
#include <gtkmm.h>
class mainwindow : public Gtk::Window
{
public:
    mainwindow();

protected:
    Gtk::TextView myTextEntry;
    Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::CssProvider> provider;
};
```

*mainwindow.cpp*

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

mainwindow::mainwindow()
{
    this->set_default_size(300,300);
    this->set_child(myTextEntry);
    provider=Gtk::CssProvider::create();
    provider->load_from_data("#MainCodeText{"
        "font-size:22px;"
    "}");
myTextEntry.set_name("MainCodeText");
myTextEntry.get_style_context()->add_provider(TextViewStyle,1);
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
#include "mainwindow.h"

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create();

    return app->make_window_and_run<mainwindow>(argc,argv);
}
```